# Is "some terrible secret" right?

Tags: word-usage

I saw this sentence in my book:

> We ofen read in novels how a seemingly respectable person or family has **some terrible secret** which has been conceled from stangers for years.

I think it should be **some terrible secrets**. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

No, **some terrible secret** is acceptable.

The subject is "*a* seemingly respectable person *or* family." This is a singular subject, and it makes sense that a singular person (or a singular family) might have a singular secret. They might also have multiple secrets, but nothing says this is always the case.

Comment: However, **some** represents **several**, so it can not be the **one**. Am I right?

Comment: If it is as you said, it should be: *We ofen read in novels how a seemingly respectable person or family has **a** terrible secret which has been conceled from stangers for years.*

Comment: @Y.zeng no, "some" is a very versatile word and has several different meanings. [At Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/some#English), part-of-speect *Determinator*, definition 4: "A certain, an unspecified or unknown." Example: "The sequence S converges to zero for some initial value v."

Comment: So are there difference between **some secrets** and **some secret**?

Comment: @Y.zeng yes, those are two entirely different uses of the word. "Some secrets" means multiple secrets, at least two. "Some secret" means a singular secret whose nature is unspecified. (Or it could mean "a remarkable secret" which is definition 6.)

Comment: I seem to understand a lit.

Comment: Why not say: He is **a** some acrobat!, but say: He is some acrobat!

Comment: @Y.zeng because that is how the word is used. **some** is a drop-in replacement for **a remarkable**. To say **a some** is redundant. Why it is that way, I do not know.

Comment: **a remarkable** or **adjective which nature is unspecified**.  Those are two situations.

Answer (score 0):

> We ofen read in novels how a seemingly respectable person or family has some terrible secret which has been conceled from stangers for years.

EDIT

The phrase *some terrible secret* is in fact commonly used.

There are several mistakes, however, as corrected below.  Please note we need a comma before the non-restrictive relative pronoun *which*.

> We [often] read in novels how a seemingly respectable person or family has some terrible secret[,] which has been [concealed] from [strangers] for years.

Please choose your reading materials with care.

Comment: *Some terrible secret* is perfectly acceptable English and is actually the more common phrase of the two.